# Jquery Get last row of table within last element in a series

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a series of slides based off of sections:

```
<div id="slides">
    <section id="first">
        <section>
            <table>
                <thead>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="somethingUnique">
                    ...
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </section>
        <section>
            <table>
                <thead>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="somethingUnique">
                    ...
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </section> 
       ...
    </section>
</div>
```

I need to select grab the ID of the last row from the table in the last section of #first section.

I'm using the following Jquery, getting "undefined" back...any ideas?

```
    var lastListItem = $('#first:last-child table>tbody>tr:last').attr("id");
    alert(lastListItem);
```

Comment: I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tdjzj/) and it seems to return `somethingUnique`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$('#first table:last tr:last')
```

or:

```
$('#first tr:last')
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/QMzHH/

Answer (score 1):

```
var lastListItem = $("#first").find("section").last().find("tr").last().attr("id");
```

I prefer using [0].id instead of .attr("id") since its one less method call; however, if you're not positive that you'll always have a table in that DOM position, attr is safer.

Comment: You can use pseudo-selectors to find items, but I chose to write my answer using chained methods for better performance.

Comment: Did you measure that this solution is actually faster on browsers that support `querySelectorAll()`?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi No, depending on the browser, querySelectorAll could be faster. However, its still a method which needs to parse a long string to determine what kind of elements to look for in the DOM. I prefer utilizing querySelectorAll (or pseudo-selectors in jQuery) when the selector is shorter, not longer.

Comment: I can't see how separate calls to `find()` and `last()` would make it faster, parsing the selector is not the bottle neck. You need to show some facts to support your claim

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastListItem = $('#first section:last  table tr:last').attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

**[.find():](http://api.jquery.com/find/)**

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

```
​$("#first")​.find("tr:last").attr("id")
```

or more simply in this case:

```
$("#first tr:last").attr("id")
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zeef4/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

The other answers work but the problem with your attempt is the fact that 
`:last-child` has to be applied to the child element (`section`), not the parent (`#first`). The following should work

```
$('#first section:last-child table>tbody>tr:last').attr("id");
```

And could be simplified to

```
$('#first section:last-child tr:last-child').attr("id");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e7mUD/1