# Add a row to table before last row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following HTML/Script code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".AddItem").click(function(){
            $(this).parents('table tr:last').after('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="text" name="item[]" value=""></td></tr>');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">Items&nbsp;<a href="#" class="AddItem"><img src="images/16/button-add.png"  title="Add more Items"></a></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="item[]"  ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Count: </td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This will add a row below the row with add button. I need to add a row at the bottom of table above footer row (Count).
What selector should I use?

Please note [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786801/jquery-get-last-row-of-table-within-last-element-in-a-series) does not meet my requirement, It selects the last row.

Comment: You should create a fiddle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery: using appendTo in second to last row of table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645174/jquery-using-appendto-in-second-to-last-row-of-table)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/DegTc/)</kbd>

```
$(this).closest('table').find('tr:last').prev().after('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="text" name="item[]" value=""></td></tr>');
```

Comment: Your first version wasn't working, but this one works nice. I was thinking if I could merge find and parents.

Comment: @BobSort Glad it works now  use `.closest()` as it faster than `.parents()`

Comment: The problem with this version is that it assumes that there are at least two rows in the table. If there's just one, it won't work. Use `.before()` instead, as per Anoop Joshi's answer.

Answer (score 15):

USe `.before()` for that

```
 $(this).parents('table tr:last').before('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="text" name="item[]" value=""></td></tr>');
```

**Edit**

```
$(this).parents('table').find("tr:last").before('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="text" name="item[]" value=""></td></tr>');
```

Comment: strangely `before` adds a row before the row with button

Comment: @BobSort in your question, you mentioned that, your code will add the new row after the last row. Then if you want to add the new row before the last row, you should use before() method. Answer is straight forward..

Comment: If you read properly it say Adds after row with button (first row) pushing other rows down. at least please check your code in browser before posting.

Comment: `find().before()` works but I only had on answer vote and @Tushar was faster than you. Thanks again

Comment: its ok. It was my mistake.. I thought your current code adds the row after the last row.. Thats why i posted the answer like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
        $(".AddItem").click(function(e){
            $("tr:last", $(this).parents('table')).before('<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="text" name="item[]" value="+"/></td></tr>');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

you can also try  this